# StackOverflowError while performing external sort

Tags: java, stack-overflow, mergesort, external-sorting

I am trying to do external merge sort. Method: opening all the files in the folder 'output' and getting 1st line and sorting it, and writing it in the 'final' file and then getting the 2nd line of that file and repeating. I get an StackOverflowError. Here my file size is greater then memory.

```
 public class mergefile6 {
    public static ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    static HashMap hm = new HashMap();
    public static String line;
    public static String[][] filepoint = new String[100][2];
    public static int fileline=1;  
    public static int i=0;  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        fileread();
    }
    public static void fileread() throws Exception{     
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;       
    try {
                File folder = new File("./output/");        
                if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);        
                            int lineCount = 0;
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                                lineCount++;
                                if (1 == lineCount) {
                                    hm.put(line,file);
                                    al.add(line);
                                    filepoint[i][0]=file.toString();
                                filepoint[i][1]=Integer.toString(fileline);
                                    ++i;
                                }                                               
                            }               
                    }
                }
                if (null != fileReader){
                    try {
                            fileReader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
        if (null != bufferedReader){
                    try {
                            bufferedReader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }
        Sorting(al);
        test(al);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally { 
    }
  }
  public static void Sorting(ArrayList<String> al)throws Exception{
    int length = al.size();
    ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>(al);
    mergeSort(al, tmp,  0,  al.size() - 1);
  }
  private static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> al, ArrayList<String> tmp, int left, int right){
    //sort code
  } 

public static void test(ArrayList<String> al) throws Exception{
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    FileWriter fw = null;
        fw = new FileWriter("final",true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(al.get(0)+" \n");
        //bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        String filename = hm.get(al.get(0)).toString();
        hm.remove(al.get(0));
        al.remove(0);
        fileforward(filename,al);
}
public static void fileforward(String filename,ArrayList<String> al) throws Exception{
    long list;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    fr = new FileReader(filename);
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    for(int j=0;j<i;++j){
        if(filepoint[j][0] == filename){
            fileline = Integer.parseInt(filepoint[j][1]); 
            list = br.skip(99*fileline);
            if((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                hm.put(line,filename);
                al.add(line);
                ++fileline;
                filepoint[j][1]=Integer.toString(fileline);
                br.close(); fr.close();
            }else{}             
        }
    }
    if(al.size()==3){
    Sorting(al);
    test(al);       }                               
}   
 }
```

> What may be causing this error to come?

Comment: Error i get is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.Hashtable.hash(Hashtable.java:239)
 at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:434)
 at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:951)
 at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:711)
 at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:84)
 at sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction.run(GetPropertyAction.java:49)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:109)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(BufferedWriter.java:88)

Comment: You should place your comment as an update to your initial question. You can do it by using the *edit* button, at the end of your question, right after the tags' section.

Comment: Your code is a mess. In test you call fileforward(), and in fileforward you call test again. such recursions usually lead to a stack overflow. But I cannot help you in details because I do not understand your code and it does not run in my eclipse: test() produces a ArrayIndexOutBoundException which is not even caught by your main program, and if would be caught it would be silently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an overflow caused by the mutual calls between `fileforward()` and `test()`. I don't know try debugging the ArrayList's size with logs or prints. If it's always equal to 3 that's the problem.

Comment: :  Yes.. It says equals to 3, so what is the problem? Sorry i am new at this and not sure what is causing the error.  Here i have 3 input data files, and the ArrayList stores 1st line from each, then perform the sort operation on them, prints the 1st line and removes that line from the ArrayList and stores line2 from that specific file. So it should be 3 till the EOF is reached.

Comment: They are invoking each other undefinitely which cause an overflow in the subroutines calls stack. Inter-fuction recursion should be used only under controlled enviroments. I can't understand the code so I can't give you advice on how write it. Try re-thinking the problem in order to solve without using inter-function recursion.